# Testing Data in mongodb - time varies

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, pytest, mongoengine

I'm currently testing my database accessibility and I run into a serious problem. I'm mocking the database and insert a user object which has a registration date. That date is first written into a variable and then passed to the data which should result in the exact same value. Well, it doesn't...

**data.py**

```
class User(Document):
    email = EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = StringField(max_length=50)
    last_name = StringField(required=True, max_length=50)
    registration_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow())
    last_login = DateTimeField()
```

**test_storage.py**

```
import datetime
import pytest

from mongoengine.connection import (
    connect,
    get_connection,
)

from mongodb.data import User
from storage.users import get_users


FMT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def mock_db():
    connect('mongoenginetest', host='mongomock://localhost')

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def mock_user(mock_db):
    user = {
        'email': 'wijgowol@kogun.gi',
        'registration_date': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
        'last_name': 'Bowen',
        'first_name': 'Charlie',
    }
    db_user = User (**user)
    db_user.save()

    return user, db_user



def test_storage_get_user(mock_user):
    user, db_user = mock_user

    users = get_users()
    assert len(users) == 1
    assert type(users[0]) == User

    u = users[0]
    assert u == db_user
    assert u.email == user['email']
    assert u.registration_date == user['registration_date']
    assert u.last_name == user['last_name']
    assert u.first_name == user['first_name']
```

When I run the test I get the following result:

```
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_storage_get_user _____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

mock_user = ({'email': 'wijgowol@kogun.gi', 'first_name': 'Charlie', 'last_name': 'Bowen', 'registration_date': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 4, 10, 49, 56, 814025)}, <User: User object>)

def test_storage_get_user(mock_user):
    user, db_user = mock_user

    users = get_users()
    assert len(users) == 1
    assert type(users[0]) == User

    u = users[0]
    assert u == db_user
    assert u.email == user['email']
>       assert u.registration_date == user['registration_date']
E       assert datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 4, 10, 49, 56, 814000) == datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 4, 10, 49, 56, 814025)
E        +  where datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 4, 10, 49, 56, 814000) == <User: User object>.registration_date

app/test/test_impl.py:53: AssertionError
```

Why does the time vary there?

Comment: Why should I do that? It is already `datetime.datetime`

Comment: I meant wrapping `user['registration_date']`

Comment: This is also already of the type `datetime.datetime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're defaulting the registration date in `data.py` then why are you even setting it when you create the user dict? Maybe this is what's causing it. Also why don't you just create a `User` instead?

***You have this:***

```
user = {
    'email': 'wijgowol@kogun.gi',
    'registration_date': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
    'last_name': 'Bowen',
    'first_name': 'Charlie',
}
db_user = User (**user)
db_user.save()
```

***I'd use this instead:***

```
db_user = User(
    email = 'wijgowol@kogun.gi',
    last_name = 'Bowen',
    first_name = 'Charlie'
).save()
```

**Edit:** *As per my comment.*

Also if the registration date is always set when a user is created then why not just use the `_id`'s [timestamp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/)?

**Edit2:**
As per the API Reference you need to use a [Complex DateTimeField](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html?highlight=datetimefield#mongoengine.fields.ComplexDateTimeField) the regular `DatetimeField` doesn't handle microseconds well.

*From the* `DatetimeField` *reference:*

> **Note: Microseconds are rounded to the nearest millisecond.**
>
> Pre UTC microsecond support is effectively broken. Use ComplexDateTimeField if you need accurate microsecond support.

Comment: I do this so I can later check that the Date is the same as I provided. I have the dict and the User object which then I can compare if everything is as I told it should be.
Of course I could do that like you did but why do I get this Error?

Comment: I believe it's because it may be using the default and generating the registration date itself. Try without using the default date in `data.py`. I could definitely be wrong but that seems like what it's doing because it's only off by 25 microseconds. Also if the registration date is always set when a user is created then why not just use the `_id`'s [timestamp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/)?

Comment: Hang on a second.. what does `get_users` do? Maybe that's your issue. Somehow it's either making a new `User` or new `datetime`.

Comment: neither, I tried without the default and `get_users` ist clean. I think this is a Bug. I tested a bit and every time the millis are something like `123456` they get saved like this `123000`. So I think this is a Bug from either `mongoengine` or `mongodb`